# JPA call Store Procedure returned wrong result

Tags: jpa, stored-procedures, eclipselink

I am using JPA native query to call a stored procedure and map the return result to a class

```
createNativeQuery(String sqlString, Class resultClass);
```

Here sqlString is a stored procedure in this format:

```
{call storeProcedureName parameter1, paramter2, parameter3}
```

I noticed that when one of the parameter contains a forward slash (/), the result result will be wrong. Has any body encountered this problem before and how to solve it? thanks

I am using EclipseLink and glassfish server.

Comment: You will have to debug a bit further to see if the parameter is passed to the stored procedure correctly or if it is the stored proc that isn't able to handle the forward slash as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in-lining the parameters into your SQL, or using parameters on your query?  You should use parameters on your query, in-lining parameters into SQL is very bad (can lead to SQL injection attacks).

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Native#Parameters